# correct error handling for catch HttpWebRequest c#

Tags: c#

I have a try/catch on an http request. I am using it incase there is no internet or the url is unavailable. However the catch has no specific error so always goes there for any error. How do I make it more specific so I will see other error messages for debugging?

```
try
{
    WebRequest.Create("https://lon1.blynk.cloud/external/api/get?token=X&V40").Method = "GET";
    int emailrequest = Int32.Parse(new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create("https://lon1.blynk.cloud  /external/api/get?token=X&V40").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());

    if (emailrequest == 1)
    {
        if (timer2.Enabled == false)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }

    connectionerror = 0; //We have achieved a connection so set to 0
    Connection_Attempt_Textbox.Text = connectionerror.ToString();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    connectionerror++;
    Connection_Attempt_Textbox.Text = connectionerror.ToString();
    connectionlost = 1;
}
```

There error I recieve if no internet that I would like to be the only reason I go into the catch:

```
-       $exception  {"The remote name could not be resolved: 'lon1.blynk.cloud'"}   System.Net.WebException

+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}


        Status  NameResolutionFailure   System.Net.WebExceptionStatus

+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you just need  `catch (Exception ex) {...` and then `ex` is your exception object which you can get information out of. Or you might want `catch (WebException ex)` which will only catch that exception type. Is there any reason you are using `WebRequest` which is basically deprecated, and not the newer `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestMessage`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the exception object? Can you show me how I would write that? Above is the error I get.
I'll have a look at HttpRequestMessage, is there any reason to swap from WebRequest?
Thanks

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/using-exceptions. `HttpClient` is newer and much easier to use, it also has proper asynchronous capabilities.